# using ssis for polling database value

Tags: sql, ssis

How can i use a SSIS for checking if a database value changes from 0 to 1 (every 5 second)?
I've tryed with a For Loop Container but it seems it doesn't works.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS does not have a "timer" like a programming language. i believe your best approach in this scenario  would be to add the SSIS package to a SQL job and call the job every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a waste of CPU cycles to me.  I'd prefer an event based solution using triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with SQL Broker for this sort of thing